# Vertically align title page in latex

Tags: vertical-alignment, titles

I want to vertically align document title and names in title page. My current LaTeX looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\title{ ... }}
\author{ ... }
\date{{ ... }}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

But this shows the content somewhat in top half part of the doc. I want to center it vertically. [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/vertically-center-text-on-a-page) asks to use `\vplace`. But I am not able to figure out how to use `\vplace` in title page.

I tried

```
\begin{vplace}[1]
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
\end{vplace}
```

and also

```
\begin{vplace}[1]
\title{ ... }}
\author{ ... }
\date{{ ... }}
\end{vplace}
```

But it is giving error like `Environment vplace undefined`. It seems that it requires `memoir` class. But overleaf does not recognize `memoir` document class. How can I achieve same in document class?

Answer (score 1):

The `titling` package has tools to customize  the `maketitle` command. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-9.5ex}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\vfill\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{\vfill\clearpage}
\title{The Quangle-Wangle’s Hat}
\author{Edward Lear}
\date{(1876)}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlingpage}
\maketitle
\end{titlingpage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would for `TiKz` since there is better control over alignment(my perspective) and calc code is easier to comprehend for me -- for the `TiKz` option please see the edit

[Vertically Center title page : Article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290432/vertically-center-title-page-article)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\title{Project Title}
\date{2016-31-01}
\author{Author Name}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{titling}
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\null\mbox{}\vfill}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookd{\vfill\null}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{titlingpage}
        \maketitle
    \end{titlingpage}
    
\end{document}
```

**EDIT ---title page with tikz**

[Formatting a title page, using Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416942/formatting-a-title-page-using-tikz)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[line width = 2pt] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-1in)$) 
  rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-1in,1in)$);
  \draw[line width = 1pt, blue] ($(current page.center) + (-1in,0in)$) -- 
    ($(current page.center) + (1in,0in)$)node[pos=0.5,above](){%
    \textbf{\LARGE Escola Secundária Domingos Sequeira}\\[4.5cm]
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\vfill

% Bottom of the page
\centering{\bf \large \today}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: first one worked. But can you please explain those commands a bit?  `\usepackage{titling} \renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\null\mbox{}\vfill} \renewcommand\maketitlehookd{\vfill\null}`

Comment: The format for typesetting the `\maketitle` command is fixed in the standard
`LATEX` classes. The `titling` package provides some controls for modifying the appearance of the titling information presented via `\maketitle`

Comment: hook commands are provided so that additional elements may be added
to `\maketitle`

Comment: http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/titling/titling.pdf  -- refer page 4 of the documentation